# Log in user after accept invitation using rails with devise_invitable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, devise-invitable

I use devise_invitable with Rails and need some help. I want make user logged in after accept invitation. Here is my InvitationsController

```
class InvitationsController < Devise::InvitationsController
  def update
    if User.accept_invitation!(user_params)
      # log in user here
      redirect_to dashboard_show_path, notice: t('invitaion.accepted')
    else
      redirect_to root_path, error: t('invitation.not_accepted')
    end
  end

  private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:invitation_token, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
end
```

You can see comment in code

```
# log in user here
```

here I want log in the user who has accept the invitation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method your looking for is `sign_in`, try this:

```
def update
  if User.accept_invitation!(user_params)
    sign_in(params[:user])
    redirect_to dashboard_show_path, notice: t('invitaion.accepted')
  else
    redirect_to root_path, error: t('invitation.not_accepted')
  end
end
```

However I should note that devise_invitable, by default, signs in users after they have accepted an invitation. See the default update action [here](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/invitations_controller.rb#L37), if you wish to use the default functionality simply call the `super` method or don't implement the update action at all.

Comment: `sign_in(params[:user])`

Leads to an error

`Could not find a valid mapping for {"invitation_token"=>"xQjPyREVoFwW1pwejm9r", "password"=>"12345678", "password_confirmation"=>"12345678"}`

Using `super` or changing method realisation similar to default update action works well . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minor update for the `Noz` version:

```rb
# invitations_controller.rb

def update
  user = User.accept_invitation!(update_resource_params)

  if user
    sign_in(user)
    redirect_to root_path, notice: t('devise.layout.edit_invitation.accepted')
  else
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end

private

def update_resource_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:password, :first_name, :last_name, :invitation_token)
end
```

This definition update won't throw `Could not find a valid mapping for {...}` and instead login the user after invitation acceptance.